# Running two parallel custom receiver streams in local setup with Spark streaming for local test

Tags: java, spark-streaming

I am currently learning how to use Spark streaming and would like to do some experiments with joining parallel streams. For this purpose I would like to setup two parallel streams with custom Receiver classes just generating random numbers. So far I got everything setup.

However there seems to be a problem with running two custom receivers instances of the same receiver class on one Spark context. When I run only one everything works perfectly. As soon as I wire in the second one there seems to be some infinite loop error. The symptom is that I do not get any output anymore. For better understanding I put a simple [example showing the problem on github](https://github.com/muthenberg/spark-streaming-custom-parallel-streams)

If you clone the project everything should work fine. Just uncomment line 18 in Application.java and you should see that the output of the print call is gone. This is either a bug in Spark streaming or my understanding of how the library works is not good enough to use it properly. Either way I hope there are some experts here, who are able to help me with the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*headdeask* 
Luckily there is a "Related" feature in Stackoverflow. Just found my solution by looking over the "Related" threads. The accepted answer to the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116079/why-does-spark-streaming-stop-working-when-i-send-two-input-streams?rq=1) also solves the problem described here.

So the solution is, that in a local setup if you use the master URL "local[2]" you only get 2 worker threads. Both are used by the custom receivers in this setup. To get a third processing thread one needs to use the master URL "local[3]".